# Sequence of function applications

Tags: scala

I have some lambda expressions as follows:

```
val foo : (Int => Option[String]) = (x: Int) => Some("foo")
val bar : (Int => Option[String]) = (x: Int) => Some("bar")

Seq(foo,bar).flatMap(_ (2))
```

and evaluates as I expect:

```
res0: Seq[String] = List(foo, bar)
```

Now I will change the lambda expressions to the make them take an Int and return a toy Future computation:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

val foo1 : (Int => Future[Option[String]]) = (x: Int) => Future successful Some("foo")
val bar1: (Int => Future[Option[String]]) = (x: Int) => Future successful Some("bar")
```

I would like to get the same result back as before i.e. `List("foo", "bar")` but I am not sure how to achieve it. I think I need to use Monad Transformers but not entirely sure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which Monad Transformer to use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42290243/which-monad-transformer-to-use)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Future.sequence` to convert the result to a `Future[List]` and then flatten it:

```
Future.sequence(Seq(foo1,bar1).map(_ (2))).map(_.flatten)
```

This will return a `Future[List[String]]`, you can then handle the `Future` as you seem fit.