# Which Monad Transformer to use?

Tags: scala, monads, scalaz, monad-transformers

I am trying to write the validate function below so that the validation stops after the first error encountered. The return type of `three` is different to the other functions. Which monad transformer do I use in order to make this code compile?

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global


def one(a : String): Disjunction[Int, String] =
  a == "one" match {
    case true => \/-("one")
    case false => -\/(2)
  }

def two(a : String): Disjunction[Int, String] =
  a == "two" match {
    case true => \/-("two")
    case false => -\/(3)
  }

def three(a : String): Future[Disjunction[Int, String]] =
  Future (a == "three") map {
    case true => \/-("three")
    case false => -\/(4)
  }

def validate(a : String) = for {
  e1 <- one(a)
  e2 <- two(a)
  e3 <- EitherT(three(a))
} yield (e1 |+| e2 |+| e3)
```

**Compilation Error:**

```
Error:(27, 7) type mismatch;
 found   : scalaz.EitherT[scala.concurrent.Future,Int,String]
 required: scalaz.\/[?,?]
  e3 <- EitherT(three(a))
     ^
Error:(66, 7) type mismatch;
 found   : scalaz.EitherT[scala.concurrent.Future,Int,String]
 required: scalaz.\/[?,?]
  e3 <- EitherT(three(a))
     ^
```

Comment: Any reason why you would not either wrap `one`and `two` in a `Future` or `Await` the result of `three` ?

Comment: You wanna have a look at the `EitherT` monad transformer, your third `<-` is not returning the `String`, it's giving you the whole `Disjunction` which may not be what you want (the first two access the `String` part of the disjunction).

Comment: @EndeNeu I tried the EitherT but still get compilation errors. Please see updated question along with compilation errors. I was using DisjunctionT before (which is just a wrapper for EitherT) with same results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two general approaches you can take in a situation like this. The first is to make all your methods return the stack you know you'll be working with (in this case `EitherT[Future, Int, ?]`), or you can have each individual method return the type that most accurately captures its own effects, and then raise the values you get appropriately when you compose them.

The first approach can make usage more syntactically convenient if you know exactly what that usage is going to look like, but the latter approach is more flexible, and in my opinion generally the better choice. In your case it'd look something like this:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

def one(a: String): Disjunction[Int, String] = (a == "one").either("one").or(2)
def two(a: String): Disjunction[Int, String] = (a == "two").either("two").or(3)

def three(a: String): EitherT[Future, Int, String] = EitherT(
  Future(a == "three").map(_.either("three").or(4))
)

def validate(a: String) = for {
  e1 <- EitherT.fromDisjunction[Future](one(a))
  e2 <- EitherT.fromDisjunction[Future](two(a))
  e3 <- three(a)
} yield (e1 |+| e2 |+| e3)
```

And then:

```
scala> validate("one").run.foreach(println)
-\/(3)

scala> validate("x").run.foreach(println)
-\/(2)
```

If for some reason you had a plain old `Future` that you wanted to use in the `for`-comprehension, you could lift it into the `EitherT[Future, String, A]` with `.liftM[EitherT[?[_], String, ?]]`.

(Note that this method probably isn't terribly useful, since it'll never succeed (a string can't be equal to `"one"`, `"two"`, and `"three"` at the same time), but at least the composition works out.)

About how to pick the monad transformer stack more generally: you just turn the types inside out, so that `Future[Disjunction[Int, ?]]` becomes `EitherT[Future, Int, ?]`, etc. In this case specifically, `Future` does not have a monad transformer (it's not traversable and it's impossible to implement `FutureT` without blocking), so you know it has to go on the inside, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing much to add to Travis' answer (as usual), but in the case you're using this in a Play! application, maybe https://github.com/Kanaka-io/play-monadic-actions can provide some help.

Comment: Can ?| operator be used outside of a Play Controller ?